# Symfony 4.1 - Validate one field to check if email or phone number

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony4

I use Symfony 4.1 and I want to valid one field, name's identifier, it can take an email or one phone number.

**So I want valid if field is an email, or if field is a phone number.**

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    'op'    => new Assert\Required([
        new Assert\Choice(['choices' => Operators::toArray()]),
    ]),
    'value' => [
        new Assert\Required([
            new Assert\Collection([
                'identifier' => [
                    new Assert\Email(),
                ],
            ]),
        ]),
    ],
]);

return $this->validator->validate($data, $constraint);
```

The body I send is:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "value":  {
            "identifier": "john.doe@example.com",
            "identifierType": "email"
        }
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "value":  {
            "identifier": "+33600000000",
            "identifierType": "phone"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Read [How to Create a Custom Validation Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: What gp_sflower said, you need to create a custom constraint.